# Android - Use custom font in PdfRenderer

Tags: android, pdf, pdfrenderer

I want to display a [pdf file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Qvl9awsSF9VlA2ZnhvYnRzNHc) in an android app. I used the pdf renderer sample app from android studio. The rendered image does not have any text by default. That is because the pdf uses a [custom font](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Qvl9awsSF9UnQ1MUdlcndnQWc/view?usp=sharing) which has to be installed on the PC to display the file.
PS: It would be very helpful if you could use the same android sample(PdfRendererBasic) app from android studio. 
Thank You.
[image: Rendered pdf should look like this]

Comment: Hi @Kabilan..
Did you got any luck in using Custom font in Android PdfRenderer?